# How do I join two tables in R when the key column names don't match?

Tags: r, join, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I have a main_table that has a column called `category`, then I have a category_table with an `id` column. They function like primary and foreign keys, but when I try and join the tables, the ID's don't get replaced with the corresponding names from the `name` column of the category_table.

For clarity here is the tables and column names

```
main_table        category_table
[category]        [id]
                  [name]
```

`category` and `id` have the keys. I want the `name` from the category_table in my geom, but the `id` number keeps being plotted.

I was expecting the code below to join the tables so that I could have category$names alongside stuff in my main_table.

```
join_table <- inner_join(category_table, main_table,by="id")
```

But when I plot, the `category` field returns numbers instead of names. How do I get names to show up in my plot instead of ID's?

Comment: Hi siekertr21! Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: The question in your title is *'How do I join two tables in R when the key column names don't match?'*, but the question in your description is '*How do I get names to show up in my plot instead of ID's?*' - different questions!

Comment: it's hard to answer the second one when you've included no code or data. You'll get better answers if you include a minimal reproducible example of your problem

Comment: I can't imagine the code as shown works at all. There is no "id" column in `main_table` so it should error out - `inner_join(data.frame(category=1), data.frame(id=1,name="a"), by="id")` for instance gives the error "*Error in inner_join():
! Join columns must be present in data.*" You probably need `by = c("id" = "category")`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what is actually going on with your code, because you haven't posted it. In the code you have posted though, as [thelatemail has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76848357/how-do-i-join-two-tables-in-r-when-the-key-column-names-dont-match/76848402#comment135478108_76848357), the inner join wouldn't work, because there is no id column in the main table. You need to join on `c("id"="category")`

Here is how I would do something similar to this:

```
# create toy datasets
category_table <- data.frame(
    id = 1:3,
    name = c("Primates", "Carnivores", "Rodents")
)

main_table <- data.frame(
    category = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),
    entity_name = c("Human", "Chimpanzee", "Lion", "Squirrel", "Mouse", "Rat"),
    coolness = c(10, 6, 9, 4, 3, 2)
)

library(tidyverse)

# perform join
join_table <- inner_join(category_table, main_table, by=c("id"="category"))

# plot result
ggplot(join_table, aes(x=name, y=coolness, fill=entity_name)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image: plot]